# Can the Nvidia GT 520 support triple monitors?

Tags: graphics-card

I would like to know if the nvidia GT 520 can support 3 distinct monitors at the sametime. It has 3 video outputs, 1xDVI, 1xVGA and 1xDisplay Port but I'm unable to confirm with Nvidia's [product page](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-520/specifications) if the graphic card can use all 3 ports simultaneously.

Comment: "Please refer to the Add-in-card manufacturers' website for actual shipping specifications."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [forum entry](http://forums.techarena.in/monitor-video-cards/1424906.htm) it does not. As far as I know, you will need a second card to do this, or a high end card.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for you card specifically, though typically support for more than two displays from a single card has been reserved for the Quadro line. The new GTX 680 does support triple displays, so there is hope that the entire 600 will support it.

Comment: The entire 600 series BETTER support it - this is one area where AMD has been ahead of Nvidia for several generations now!